# Installing python development package on RHEL

Tags: python, rhel6

I have been trying to install python development package on my red hat machine but not able to find the package any where.

My server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)( x86_64 GNU/Linux) with python 2.6.6 on-board

The repo list dose not include the required package and i have no access to alter it also.

I have tried doing a "yum install python-devel" and "yum search .." but have not been successful.

From where can i grab hold of this package? Any external link available?

Answer (score 2):

1.-> yum install epel-release

After that ;

```
[root@srv1 ~]# yum search python-devel

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * epel: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * epel-source: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * extras: mirror.daniel-jost.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: mirror.daniel-jost.net
============================================================= N/S matched: python-devel ==============================================================

+dbus-python-devel.i686 : Libraries and headers for dbus-python
+dbus-python-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and headers for dbus-python
+gstreamer-python-devel.i686 : Headers for developing programs that will use gstreamer-python
+gstreamer-python-devel.x86_64 : Headers for developing programs that will use gstreamer-python
+nemo-python-devel.x86_64 : Python bindings for Nemo
+ ---->>>>> python-devel.x86_64 : The libraries and header files needed for Python development
+qscintilla-python-devel.noarch : Development files for QScintilla PyQt4 bindings
+wxPython-devel.x86_64 : Development files for wxPython add-on modules
```